# Excel - Formula to calculate difference between columns with blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with values similar to the table below.

```
-------------------------------------
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
-------------------------------------
|   95|     |   98|   96|   95|     |
-------------------------------------
|   96|   95|     |   92|   91|     |
-------------------------------------
|   93|     |   92|   98|   94|     |
-------------------------------------
|   92|   98|     |   95|   92|     |
-------------------------------------
|   95|     |   99|   92|   98|     |
-------------------------------------
```

The formula for `F1` should be `=(B1-A1)+(C1-B1)+(D1-C1)+(E1-D1)`

However, some cells are blank. So, if the cell is blank, it should take the next cell.

eg; `F1` should be `=(C1-A1)+(D1-C1)+(E1-D1)`
and `F2` should be `=(B2-A2)+(D2-B2)+(E2-D2)`
and so on...

Is there a formula to automate this?

Comment: Is it possible for A1 and E1 also to be blank? For the all the examples you've shown, the answer is just E1-A1 because the cells in between cancel out.

Comment: Yes. Any cell can be blank. The cell in F can be 0 or negative or positive.

Comment: So, to be clear, your third row should resolve to `-186`, and not `-93`, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula:

`= (B1-A1) + (C1-B1) + (D1-C1) + (E1-D1)`

can also be written as:

`= B1 - A1 + C1 - B1 + D1 - C1 + E1 - D1`

or

`= - A1 + (B1 - B1) + (C1 - C1) + (D1 - D1) + E1`

where only the first and last values prevail as all other void themselves, thus leaving this formula:

`= - A1 + E1`

So the formula then becomes the `last non-blank value` minus the `first non-blank value`.

Try this formula:

```
= INDEX( $A1:$E1, 0, AGGREGATE( 14, 6, COLUMN(1:1) / ( $A1:$E1 <> "" ), 1 ))
- INDEX( $A1:$E1, 0, AGGREGATE( 15, 6, COLUMN(1:1) / ( $A1:$E1 <> "") ,1 ))
```

See these pages for further explanations on the Worksheet Functions used:

[AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df), [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd).